# Custom keys for Android Volley images

Tags: java, android

When creating a Volley ImageLoader it requires a ImageCache object to be passed in as a parameter. The ImageCache is an interface,

```
public interface ImageCache {
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url);
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap);
}
```

, and putBitmap will be called by Volley whenever it successfully downloads an image, and it will use the URL passed into the call to get everything going,

```
imageView.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader)
```

, and call putBitmap itself. This will associate the url as the key to get the bitmap from the ImageCache.

My problem is that the URLs I am passing in have hashed time stamps for query parameters, thus I won't be able to use the raw URL as a key to get the bitmap later since the hashed timestamp will be different.

I see that I have two options. Either truncate the timestamp to use the url, or find a way to use some other value for the key.

I would ideally like to use a String value that is in a custom model which the url is in also, but I don't see any way to change the fact that the url is all I have to work with in the ImageCache, and I cannot easily fetch the model containing the id easily from the URL.

Is truncating the URL my best option?

tl;dr Can I use something other than the URL for a key with a Volley ImageCache?

Comment: If you can retrieve the same bitmap with or without the timestamp in the URL, why not just truncate it? If that's not acceptable, you may have to consider modifying Volley to suit your needs.

Comment: I cannot retrieve the same bitmap without the hash timestamp because it is used for security.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest modifying the source of Volley to suit your needs. I've got a similar use-case which I haven't implemented yet - from memory it shouldn't be too tricky.